# String split into vector<char*> overwrites vector elements

Tags: c++, string

Using the following code mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/6361644, I wrote the following code to parse a string into a vector, where each element is separated by white space.

```
std::string line = "ls -l -a";
std::string cmd;
std::vector<char*> argv;
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str(line); 
std::string tmp;
getline(ss, cmd, ' ');
argv.push_back( const_cast<char*>(cmd.c_str() ) );
while(getline(ss, tmp, ' '))
    argv.push_back( const_cast<char*>(tmp.c_str() ) );
argv.push_back(NULL);
```

Printing argv after this code gives

```
{gdb) print argv                                                                         
$22 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {0x26014 "ls", 0x2602c "-a", 0x2602c "-a", 0x0}
```

I'm not sure why the second element is being overwritten. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't actually use the code mentioned in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing dangling pointers (in an ill-formed way no less! the proper way to store pointers to c-style strings is `const char*`, not `char*`).

In this (`const`-corrected) loop:

```
std::vector<const char*> argv;
// ...
while(getline(ss, tmp, ' '))
    argv.push_back(tmp.c_str());
```

every subsequent iteration will clear `tmp`, invalidating the previous pointer that you had stored. Every `tmp.c_str()` you pushed back is immediately freed by `getline()`. So all subsequent accesses are undefined.

You have to take ownership of all the strings, you can do so by instead storing the full `string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> argv;
// ...
while(getline(ss, tmp, ' '))
    argv.push_back(std::move(tmp));
```

And now `argv` actually owns all of its own resources.

Answer (score -1):

The pointer returned by `c_str()` points to a `std::string`'s internal data.

This pointer is only valid until the string is destroyed, or modified. Once the `std::string` is destroyed, or modified, the pointer is no longer valid.

```
while(getline(ss, tmp, ' '))
    argv.push_back( const_cast<char*>(tmp.c_str() ) );
```

Setting aside the issue of casting the `const`-ness away, which is already a red flag: each time the `while` loop iterates the contents of `tmp` get replaced by the next line in the `ss` file.

This automatically invalidates the `c_str()` that was obtained on the previous iteration of the `while` loop.

The correct solution here is to parse all the individual words into a `std::vector<std::string>`, first.

Then, once this vector is initialized, iterate over the vector and obtain each individual string's `c_str()`, to construct the vector of raw character pointers.

Even better: use a `std::vector<char>` instead of a `std::string`, add an explicit '\0' character at the end of each vector, and the ugly `const_cast` will not be necessary.

Comment: Why would you suggest `vector<char>` to store null-terminated strings? That's exactly what `string` is for. -1.

Comment: Because he needs a `char *`, for an obvious `exec()`.

Comment: Using the wrong container and manually mucking around with null terminators is much uglier than a `const_cast`

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. My opinion is that using a `std::vector<char>` to set up a vector of parameters to `exec()`, after which the process will not exist, is cleaner than an ugly `const_cast`.